# Iterating over arrays with mustache

Tags: ruby, mustache

How do I obtain a reference to the current element in the iteration?

```
{{#my_array}}
    <p>{{__what_goes_here?__}}</p>
{{/my_array}}
```

I hope I am just overlooking the obvious.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

According to [the spec's changelog](https://github.com/mustache/spec/blob/master/Changes), the implicit iterator (`.`) was added in v1.1.0 of the spec.  Every Mustache library that implements at least v1.1.0 should support this.

```
{{#array_of_strings}}<li>{{.}}</li>{{/array_of_strings}}
```

Comment: Note: Arrays must have implicit keys for this to work. Using this method when your array has indexes will result in one instance of the word `Array` being outputted.

Answer (score 23):

From the source code https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php

```
/**
 * The {{%IMPLICIT-ITERATOR}} pragma allows access to non-associative array data in an
 * iterable section:
 *
 *     $context = array('items' => array('foo', 'bar', 'baz'));
 *
 * With this template:
 *
 *     {{%IMPLICIT-ITERATOR}}{{#items}}{{.}}{{/items}}
 *
 * Would render as `foobarbaz`.
 *
 * {{%IMPLICIT-ITERATOR}} accepts an optional 'iterator' argument which allows implicit
 * iterator tags other than {{.}} ...
 *
 *     {{%IMPLICIT-ITERATOR iterator=i}}{{#items}}{{i}}{{/items}}
 */
```

Answer (score 9):

I walked away from my code for a bit and remembered that Ruby is duck typed. Since my array was of strings, all I needed was:

```
{{#my_array}}
    <p>{{to_s}}</p>
{{/my_array}}
```

I'll leave this question here in the hopes to save somebody else some time.